# Angular post not accessing index.php in directory and return 301 error

Tags: php, angular, post, angular8

In my angular project, I am trying to create a dummy api call. I created a directory `api/auth` and there is an `index.php` file in it. When I try to send post data to that file using `http.post` in angular, on first call it is showing `301 Moved Permanently` error. But if I try to access the url using postman, then it is working. What is wrong here?

```
this.http.post('/api/auth', parameters, request.options)
```

I have set the rest of url as base path and it will append automatically.

If I try using the url `/api/auth/index.php`, then it will work without any issue.

Please help to fix this.

Comment: due to `htaccess` redirection. You need to configure your `.htaccess` file

Comment: @Gulshan, thanks for the suggestion. But I tried adding the `.htaccess` file and still it showing the same error.